# long query in Postgres

Tags: performance, postgresql, select

Hi everybody. I have two versions of the query. It differs only with assignment operator. The query with '=' takes 1.6 seconds to execute when the query with "IS NOT DISTINCT FROM" takes more than 10 minutes. How can I optimize the second query?

Inspite of duration, there is another problem. The second query returns much more tuples than the first one as it should do. Analysing the amount of returned tuples I've found that the query B works correctly. But if the condition "IS NOT DISTINCT FROM" is stricter than the condition "=" than why it returns more tuples than the query A?

Query A:

```
INSERT INTO observations_optical(note_1,date,"RA","Dec_degree","Dec",magnitude,band,id_obser vatory,id_mpp)
SELECT note_1,date,"RA","Dec_degree","Dec",magnitude,band,observatories.id_observatory,mp_physical.id_mpp
FROM observations_comet_optical
JOIN mp_physical ON (mp_physical.designation =observations_comet_optical.mpp_designation AND mp_physical.periodic_number =observations_comet_optical.periodic_number)
JOIN observatories ON observatories.observatory_code= observations_comet_optical.observatory_code
WHERE mp_physical.mp_type='C';
```

For the first query I have the execution plan:[query A EXPLAIN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sURO4.png)
 
Query B:

```
INSERT INTO observations_optical(note_1,date,"RA","Dec_degree","Dec",magnitude,band,id_observatory,id_mpp)
SELECT note_1,date,"RA","Dec_degree","Dec",magnitude,band,observatories.id_observatory,mp_physical.id_mpp
FROM observations_comet_optical
JOIN mp_physical ON (mp_physical.designation IS NOT DISTINCT FROM observations_comet_optical.mpp_designation AND mp_physical.periodic_number IS NOT DISTINCT FROM observations_comet_optical.periodic_number)
JOIN observatories ON observatories.observatory_code IS NOT DISTINCT FROM observations_comet_optical.observatory_code
WHERE mp_physical.mp_type='C';
```

For this query I have the execution plan:[query B EXPLAIN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ALcYS.png)
 
*observations_optical* dump:

```
CREATE TABLE observations_optical (
    id_obs_o bigint NOT NULL,
    note_1 character varying,
    date timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
    "RA" time without time zone NOT NULL,
    "Dec" time without time zone NOT NULL,
    magnitude double precision,
    band character varying,
    id_observatory integer NOT NULL,
    id_mpp integer NOT NULL,
    "Dec_degree" integer
);

CREATE SEQUENCE observations_optical_id_obs_o_seq
    START WITH 1
    INCREMENT BY 1
    NO MINVALUE
    NO MAXVALUE
    CACHE 1;

ALTER SEQUENCE observations_optical_id_obs_o_seq OWNED BY observations_optical.id_obs_o;

ALTER TABLE ONLY observations_optical ALTER COLUMN id_obs_o SET DEFAULT nextval('observations_optical_id_obs_o_seq'::regclass);
ALTER TABLE ONLY observations_optical
    ADD CONSTRAINT "_C_id_obs_o" PRIMARY KEY (id_obs_o);
```

*observations_comet_optical* dump:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE observations_comet_optical(
    LIKE observations_optical
);
ALTER TABLE observations_comet_optical DROP COLUMN id_obs_o;
ALTER TABLE observations_comet_optical DROP COLUMN id_observatory;
ALTER TABLE observations_comet_optical DROP COLUMN id_mpp;
ALTER TABLE observations_comet_optical ADD COLUMN observatory_code varchar(3);
ALTER TABLE observations_comet_optical ADD COLUMN periodic_number integer;
ALTER TABLE observations_comet_optical ADD COLUMN mpp_designation varchar(30);
CREATE INDEX _I_oco_observatory_code ON observations_comet_optical USING btree (observatory_code);
CREATE INDEX _I_oco_periodic_number ON observations_comet_optical  USING btree (periodic_number);
CREATE INDEX _I_oco_mpp_designation ON observations_comet_optical  USING btree (mpp_designation);
```

*mp_physical* dump:

```
CREATE TABLE mp_physical (
    id_mpp integer NOT NULL,
    id_comet_parts integer,
    "SPK_id" nonnegative_int,
    designation character varying(30),
    name character varying(100),
    prefix character varying,
    "is_NEO" boolean,
    "H" double precision,
    "G" double precision,
    diameter nonnegative_double,
    extent character varying(30),
    extent_error nonnegative_double,
    geometric_albedo nonnegative_double,
    rot_per nonnegative_double,
    "GM" nonnegative_double,
    "BV" nonnegative_double,
    "UB" nonnegative_double,
    "spec_B" character varying(30),
    "spec_T" character varying(30),
    lca double precision,
    multiplicity nonnegative_int,
    polar_ang double precision,
    polar_slope_ang double precision,
    a double precision,
    b double precision,
    mass nonnegative_double,
    mp_type mp_type NOT NULL,
    periodic_number nonnegative_int,
    diameter_method_def character varying(200),
    discovery_info text,
    "H_sigma" nonnegative_double,
    "G_sigma" nonnegative_double,
    diameter_sigma nonnegative_double,
    geometric_albedo_sigma nonnegative_double,
    rot_per_sigma nonnegative_double,
    "GM_sigma" nonnegative_double,
    "BV_sigma" nonnegative_double,
    "UB_sigma" nonnegative_double,
    lca_sigma nonnegative_double,
    a_sigma nonnegative_double,
    b_sigma nonnegative_double,
    polar_ang_sigma nonnegative_double,
    mass_sigma nonnegative_double
);

CREATE SEQUENCE mp_physical_id_mpp_seq
    START WITH 1
    INCREMENT BY 1
    NO MINVALUE
    NO MAXVALUE
    CACHE 1;

ALTER SEQUENCE mp_physical_id_mpp_seq OWNED BY mp_physical.id_mpp;
ALTER TABLE ONLY mp_physical ALTER COLUMN id_mpp SET DEFAULT  nextval('mp_physical_id_mpp_seq'::regclass);
ALTER TABLE ONLY mp_physical
    ADD CONSTRAINT "_C_id_ap" PRIMARY KEY (id_mpp);

CREATE INDEX "_I_designation" ON mp_physical USING btree (designation);
CREATE INDEX "_I_id_comet_parts" ON mp_physical USING btree (id_comet_parts);
CREATE INDEX "_I_mp_type" ON mp_physical USING btree (mp_type);
CREATE INDEX "_I_name" ON mp_physical USING btree (name);
CREATE INDEX "_I_periodic_number" ON mp_physical USING btree (periodic_number);
CREATE INDEX _i_mp_designation ON mp_physical USING btree (designation);
CREATE INDEX _i_mp_periodic_number ON mp_physical USING btree (periodic_number);

ALTER TABLE ONLY mp_physical
    ADD CONSTRAINT comet_parts_fk FOREIGN KEY (id_comet_parts) REFERENCES comet_parts(id_comet_parts) MATCH FULL ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE RESTRICT;
```

*observatories* dump:

```
CREATE TABLE observatories (
    id_observatory integer NOT NULL,
    observatory_code character varying(3) NOT NULL,
    name character varying(200) NOT NULL,
    longitude nonnegative_double NOT NULL,
    cos double precision NOT NULL,
    sin double precision NOT NULL
);

CREATE SEQUENCE observatories_id_observatory_seq
    START WITH 1
    INCREMENT BY 1
    NO MINVALUE
    NO MAXVALUE
    CACHE 1;

ALTER SEQUENCE observatories_id_observatory_seq OWNED BY observatories.id_observatory;
ALTER TABLE ONLY observatories ALTER COLUMN id_observatory SET DEFAULT nextval('observatories_id_observatory_seq'::regclass);
ALTER TABLE ONLY observatories
    ADD CONSTRAINT "_C_id_observatory" PRIMARY KEY (id_observatory);
CREATE INDEX _i_obs_observatory_code ON observatories USING btree (observatory_code);
```

Comment: IS NOT DISTINCT FROM is not stricter than `=`.  When both members are NULL, it is  returning TRUE (`=` return  FALSE)

Comment: I see, thanks. But the problem with performance still exists.

Comment: Suspect: `JOIN observatories ON observatories.observatory_code= observations_comet_optical.observatory_code` You are joining on a non-key (varchar(3)) attribute here. Do you have any foreign keys in your data model?

Comment: I delete two foreign keys on columns id_observatory and id_mpp in order to speed up the query and recreate it afterwards.
There are no foreign keys on the columns I use in JOIN, because the aim of this query is to form such a reference. But it's guaranteed that 'observatories' contains all posible 'observatory_code' values.

Answer (score 0):

Try using "COALESCE" instead "IS NOT DISTINCT FROM".

I'm not sure if this would work better.

Comment: It works. I've substitued NULL with empty string dealing with string columns and with 0 dealing with integer columns. It's inserted correct number of records and worked near 10 seconds.